# Why is my code for calculating derivatives using central difference method keep returning 0s and 1s?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to run a program that will calculate the first and second derivative of a linear function f(x)=x and a cubic function f(x)=x^3 using central difference. I need to use function prototypes to write both of those as functions that take a double as an argument and return a double. The program is supposed to feed the functions into the same derivative operator and then calculate the derivatives at x=0.5 and x=1. When I run the code and enter in a value for x, no matter what I enter I keep getting back 1 as the first derivative and 0 as the second (for both the linear and cubic function). I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong for hours now and no matter what I try to do I still get back only 1s and 0s.

I figure I could write this without using the function prototype, but I'm not supposed to do that and it's neater using the prototypes. I've been trying to find examples and nothing has really helped me because all of the functions declared (in the examples) have multiple parameters and are using if/else statements, and I don't, I also don't know if those would even help me.

What am I doing wrong? (Sorry for the long code, I'm not sure where I've gone wrong so I didn't want to exclude anything).

Edit: I excluded that the first and second derivative need to be calculated.

```
double linearFunctionPrime(double f1Prime);
double linearFunctionDoublePrime(double f1DoublePrime);
double cubicFunctionPrime(double f2Prime);
double cubicFunctionDoublePrime(double f2DoublePrime);

int main()
{
   double x;
   double f1P, f1PP;
   double f2P, f2PP;
   cout << "Enter a number to calculate the derivatives for f(x)=x and\
   f(x)=x^3" << endl;
   cin >> x;


   cout << setprecision(10);
   f1P = linearFunctionPrime(x);
   cout << "f'(x) = " << f1P << endl;
   f1PP = linearFunctionDoublePrime(x);
   cout << "f''(x) = " << f1PP << endl;
   f2P = cubicFunctionPrime(x);
   cout << "f'(x^3) = " << f2P << endl;
   f2PP = cubicFunctionDoublePrime(x);
   cout << "f''(x^3) = " << f2PP << endl;

   return 0;
}

double h = pow(10, -5);
double linearFunctionPrime(double x)
{
   double f1, f1Prime;
   f1 = x;
   f1Prime = ((f1+h)-(f1-h))/(2.0*h);

   return f1Prime;
}
double linearFunctionDoublePrime(double x)
{
   double f1, f1DoublePrime;
   f1 = x;
   f1DoublePrime = ((f1+h)+(f1-h)-2.0*(x))/(pow(h, 2.0));

   return f1DoublePrime;
}
double cubicFunctionPrime(double x)
{
   double f2, f2Prime;
   f2 = pow(x, 3.0);
   f2Prime = ((f2+h)-(f2-h))/(2.0*h);

   return f2Prime;
}
double cubicFunctionDoublePrime(double x)
{
   double f2, f2DoublePrime;
   f2 = pow(x, 3.0);
   f2DoublePrime = ((f2+h)+(f2-h)-2.0*(f2))/(pow(h, 2.0));

   return f2DoublePrime;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **use the debugger** `gdb`; read also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: As an extra added attraction, I put a calculation for the optimal size of h in my answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is not in your code but in the way you've approached the problem.

Consider the function:

```
double cubicFunctionPrime(double x)
{
   double f2, f2Prime;
   f2 = pow(x, 3.0);
   f2Prime = ((f2+h)-(f2-h))/(2.0*h);

   return f2Prime;
}
```

expand the line:

```
f2Prime = ((f2+h)-(f2-h))/(2.0*h);
```

You get:

```
(f2+h-f2+h)/2.0*h = 2*h/2*h = 1
```

which explains why you always get 1s.

To solve:

```
double cubicFunctionPrime(double x)
{
   double f2Prime;
   f2Prime = (pow(x+h, 3.0)-pow(x-h, 3.0))/(2.0*h);

   return f2Prime;
}
```

The prime and the double prime derivative functions give you the expected result by chance, in the meaning that `f1+h = x+h;` corrispond to `f(x+h) = x+h`

Comment: I don't need to declare that f2 = pow(x,3.0)?

Comment: no. Math theory says that f'(x) = ( f(x+h) - f(x-h) ) / (2*h). Declaring f2 and using it in the previous formula will result in ( f(x) + h - f(x) + h) / (2*h) which is not what you want

Comment: your solution uses `f2` uninitialized, I guess you meant to write `x` instead of `f2`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - Dang. While I was typing, two answers beat me to the punch, and one snagged the check-mark. At this rate, I might never reach the magic 10,000. :-)

Okay. The formulas are wrong. :-)  Also, the program will not compile without a couple of include-files and a "using" directive. I changed the h's to better values, but that's another topic ...

**For starters, the formulas as presented use f(x)+h where f(x+h) is required.**

Also, as a matter of good practice, you should factor out repeated code. Each of the functions f1 and f2, and each of the first and second difference calculations should be coded only once.

SPOILER  ALERT.  Try to figure it out before reading further.

Output:

```
Enter a number to calculate the derivatives for f(x)=x and   f(x)=x^3
0.5
f'(x) = 1
f''(x) = 0
f'(x^3) = 0.75
f''(x^3) = 3
```

file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

double linearFunctionPrime(double f1Prime);
double linearFunctionDoublePrime(double f1DoublePrime);
double cubicFunctionPrime(double f2Prime);
double cubicFunctionDoublePrime(double f2DoublePrime);

int main()
{
    double x;
    double f1P, f1PP;
    double f2P, f2PP;
    cout << "Enter a number to calculate the derivatives for f(x)=x and\
       f(x)=x^3" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    cout << setprecision(10);
    f1P = linearFunctionPrime(x);
    cout << "f'(x) = " << f1P << endl;
    f1PP = linearFunctionDoublePrime(x);
    cout << "f''(x) = " << f1PP << endl;
    f2P = cubicFunctionPrime(x);
    cout << "f'(x^3) = " << f2P << endl;
    f2PP = cubicFunctionDoublePrime(x);
    cout << "f''(x^3) = " << f2PP << endl;

    return 0;
}


double f1(double x) {return x; };
double f2(double x) {return x*x*x;}
typedef decltype(f1) func;

// Showing off here. Calculate optimal h's.   
const int radix =  numeric_limits<double>::radix;
const int mantissa = numeric_limits<double>::digits;
const double h2 = pow(1.0/radix, mantissa/3);
const double h1 = pow(1.0/radix, mantissa/2);


double first_diff(func f, double x, const double h = h1) {
    return (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h);
}

double second_diff(func f, double x, const double h = h2) {
    return (f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2*f(x))/(h*h);
}

double linearFunctionPrime(double x)
{
    double f1Prime = first_diff(f1, x);
    return f1Prime;
}
double linearFunctionDoublePrime(double x)
{
    double f1DoublePrive = second_diff(f1, x);
    return f1DoublePrive;
}
double cubicFunctionPrime(double x)
{
    double f2Prime = first_diff(f2, x);
    return f2Prime;
}
double cubicFunctionDoublePrime(double x)
{
    double  f2DoublePrime = second_diff(f2, x);
    return f2DoublePrime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel better now.

Answer (score 0):

you have to calculate `fc = (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2 * h)` and `f2 = (f(x + h) - 2 * f(x) + f(x - h)) / (h * h)` where f() is your function (liner or cubic). You are calculating `fc = ((f(x)+h)-(f(x)-h))/(2.0*h)` and `f2 = ((f(x)+h)+(f(x)-h)-2.0*x)/(h*h);`
You can add 2 functions:

```
double cubicFunction(double x)
{
    return x*x*x;
}

double linerFunction(double x)
{
    return x;
}
```

and use them for calculations.

```
double h = 1e-5;

double linearFunctionPrime(double x)
{
    return (linerFunction(x + h) - linerFunction(x - h)) / (2.0*h);
}
double linearFunctionDoublePrime(double x)
{
    return (linerFunction(x + h) + linerFunction(x - h) - 2.0*linerFunction(x)) / (pow(h, 2.0));
}
double cubicFunctionPrime(double x)
{
    return (cubicFunction(x + h) - cubicFunction(x - h)) / (2.0*h);
}
double cubicFunctionDoublePrime(double x)
{
    return (cubicFunction(x + h) + cubicFunction(x - h) - 2.0*cubicFunction(x)) / (pow(h, 2.0));
}
```